# Is residue theorem really that useful?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have seen lot's of integrals that are evaluated using residue theorem. It's really beautiful and interesting application of complex analysis. Hovewer, most of (if not every) example from books about comlex analysis can be evaluated much more easily using standart real analysis methods (Gamma and Beta functions, Leibniz integral rule and so on). Does it mean that residue theorem is more about "beaty of mathematics" than about real applications or am I missing some point?

Comment: I would say that residue theorem usually requires less thinking - calculating residues themselves is purely technical, and choosing contour (and estimating / calculating integral over extra parts) is often easy. Also, residue theorem allows to sum series using integrals, which are often significantly more convenient tool.

Comment: Like Fourier transform for analytic functions, that is a trivial application of  Laurent series in the polar map $e^{i z}$ in an annulus, the application of the residuum method unfolds its real power, if the the function on the real line is a limit of complex function or series of such, analytic in the upper or lower half plane or even a mix as for $1/(z^2-m^2)$. Applications are the  distributions as fundamental solutions of partial differential equations.

Comment: Let us recall a story about Feynman (related in his book).  He was a whiz at evaluating integrals, but did not know complex analysis.  At Los Alamos, he challenged mathematicians to stump him.  They did: the integral evaluation they gave him (which could be done with residues) was beyond Feynman's expertise.

Comment: There are many interesting examples of the residue theorem [here](http://residuetheorem.com/). You can try computing these integrals without using the residue theorem by yourself.